# SumProduct Terrible Use of Resources

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a lot of formulas in my Google sheet, but this one formula doubles the processing time to calculate all by itself.  Is there a more efficient formula to take the place of this one?  This is taking 3-5 seconds all by itself.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(INT(BX42:BX119))=DAY(BX42)),--(HOUR(BX42:BX119)=8),--(MINUTE(BX42:BX119)>31),--(CK42:CK119<>""))+SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(INT(BX42:BX119))=DAY(BX42)),--(HOUR(BX42:BX119)>8),--(CK42:CK119<>""))
```

Comment: Yes. Most certainly. Though it will be tough to guess at how to construct it without a sample of some sort. You can paste anything you like here in this empty sheet of mine if you don't want to share a sample sheet yourself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_nx5Upg_X40JYA5NgOKkV0JVDM4hvZk0ntPP_zm3mo/edit?usp=sharing

With arrayformula and query() as options, it's rare to need more than one formula PER column in any spreadsheet on google sheets.

Comment: How can I share a copy of my work with only yourself?

Comment: Not sure it's possible.  Can you just anonymize a few dozen rows? enough to give me a sense of what's going on?

Comment: Which of these would be faster? =ArrayFormula(MATCH(TRUE,DAY(BX42:BX120)<>DAY(BX42),0))+39  OR =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(DAY(BX42:BX120)<>DAY(BX42),,),0)+39  I am thinking if I obtain the last row number then I can do something like this:  =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("CK42:CK"&MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(DAY(BX42:BX120)<>DAY(BX42),,),0)+39),"<>"&"")  This counts all non-blanks in column CK down to the day changes.

Comment: Seeing that you use gmail, I suppose I could share a copy of my project to only you via an email link with your permission.

Comment: Neither of those formulas would be very fast.  Those look like old legacy excel formulas.   I try to help out here on Stack since it will be helpful to others in the future potentially.  Sharing privately and helping you out would be more like a job i'm afraid.  You're welcome to reach out for that kind of help on UpWork or other job posting sites.  But the best way to get help here is to scrub a sample of your data from private info, and share a link to that sample here.

Comment: I am MattyPKing on red it.